# SQL Stored Procedure - using parameters internally

Tags: sql, table-valued-parameters

I have a stored proc that I am passing two parameters into.  One parameter is a table-valued parameter and the other is a nvarchar.  Here is the stored proc:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_sp_TestProc]    
    @P1 As [dbo].[FileIdTableType] Readonly,
    @P2 As NVARCHAR (MAX)

AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT DISTINCT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3]
      FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Field1] IN (@P1)
      AND [Field2] IN (@P2)

END
```

From code, I am then passing in my DataTable as @P1 and a string of values as @P2 that looks like `"'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'"`

It's @P2 that is causing me problems.  The Table Type works fine.  Normally when using parameters such as this in my stored procs, I create a string internally, format my string with the parameters, then call sp_executeSql to have the query run.  However, this won't work when using Table-Valued parameters.

Does anyone know how to work with table valued parameters along with nvarchar like this?  I'm sure I'm missing something simple when trying to format this correctly.
Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: using the nvarchar parameter for IN clause would only possible if you would create a dynamic sql statement, which is in general not a good idea. You could split the string and insert it into a temp table/table variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse @P2 into a temp table or table var first. You can't use the IN operator with a single string that lists a number of values.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor).